# mysql php what is the best way to obtain from table B the entries that don't match a given column in table A

Tags: php, mysql, database

The title should be self explanatory but I'll elaborate some more.

I have a table A, called "pages", the basic structure follows:

```
id | name  | content 
0  | page1 | <long html text 1>
1  | page2 | <long html text 2>
2  | page3 | <long html text 3>
3  | page4 | <long html text 4>
4  | page5 | <long html text 5>
5  | page6 | <long html text 6>
```

I have a table B, called "menus", the basic structure follows (of course there are much:

```
id | link
0  | page3
1  | page5
```

I would like to know what is the best way, resource-wise, to get all the "names" in table A which are not already used in the "link" column in table B (that is to say: page1, page2, page4, page6) and their corresponding "content"
I want the first ("names" from A which are not used in "links" from B) to be saved in an array called $name with entries like $name[0] = "page1", $name[1] = "page2" etc, and the "content" in another array called $content with entries like $content[0] =  etc

Thanks in advance to all the experts out there!

Comment: @Pieter that's wrong link to close

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936073/mysql-php-selecting-only-unique-values-from-multiple-columns-and-put-them-into-s?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

`SELECT name, content FROM pages WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT link FROM menus)`

**PHP** (pseudo)

```
Loop through results {

    $name[] = $row['name'];
    $content[] = $row['content'];

}
```

Comment: there is no column named 'name' from table menus :)

Comment: Thanks! both these answers helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

try a query like this:

```
select name,content from pages where name not in (select link from menus)
```

it will list all the items that are not from the menus table..

do the array thing yourself :)

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: The OP asked for the *best* way! ;-)

Comment: what is wrong with my query?.. there is no other way to get the data except query the values required first

Comment: there are other ways (outer join and check for null), but for many cases this is just fine and on the plus side it is perfectly readable and understandable.

Comment: @mnagel i know there are other ways to write the query.. what i meant was that you need to query first before you can get anything done on those arrays :)

Comment: Actually, it's true. MySQL optimizes this so well now that there's really no difference between this and the more 'traditional' solution. Edit your answer and I'll give you your point back.

Answer (score 0):

//this will fetch the non matched entries

```
Try using id

SELECT a.id, a.name, a.content, b.link FROM table_A AS a
LEFT JOIN table_B AS b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE b.link IS NULL

Try using name

SELECT a.id, a.name, a.content, b.link FROM table_A AS a
LEFT JOIN table_B AS b ON a.name=b.link
WHERE b.link IS NULL
```

Comment: that's a table column name i mean.. which one is common for both tables you can map it.. id or link

Comment: But you don't need to (and therefore shouldn't) include it in the SELECT clause

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'name' AS descr, name AS val FROM items WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT link FROM menus) UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'content' as descr, content as val FROM items WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT link FROM menus)
```

**PHP** (pseudo)

```
Loop through results {

    $array[$row['descr']][] = $row['val'];

}
```